# How to create an image pallette in JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery image pallette which can be dragged and dropped into a div which stores those image objects. The image pallette acts as a tool builder or tool selector. In my project I dont have any build area. I have to only select an image object and drag it into a div which stores these image objects. I wanted to ask if there is any JQuery plugin or any tutorial which has similar features or if any one can help how to go forward in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard to build yourself:

1. Make all of the images in the pallette in to jQuery UI Draggables
2. Make your storage div a jQuery UI Droppable.
3. Hook up events and logic for your app
4. Have a cold beer and call it a day :-)